# Query two inputs that have the same input

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a script that will fill in an input box when certain conditions occur.  Currently, I'm trying to use this to create a var for the input box:

```
var input = document.querySelector("input")
```

However, there are two identical queries named "input".  So instead of picking the input box that I want (the second one) it picks the first input box, which I don't want.  Is there a way for me to have the querySelector choose the second input rather than the first one, or would I need to use a different method?

Comment: Why not just give one of them an ID, and look for that? Or use `querySelectorAll`, and get the second element? Have you tried either of those?

Comment: Do you not have the option of changing the names of the input boxes?

Comment: @charlietfl: Nice one! Goes on my list...

Comment: @Carcigenicate what would I use as the Selector in querySelectorAll to get only the second input box?

Comment: @MartyMcFarty `querySelectorAll` returns a list-like object of all the matches. Just get the second  result from the list.

Comment: @Carcigenicate nevermind, I found it out.  Thanks.  This is what I used if anyone's wondering: 'var input = document.querySelectorAll("input")[1];'